# TableView as DetailView's subview with a UISplitViewController?

Tags: uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController, I used the iPad template to start.  To change the type of view in the detailview area, I'm adding my view types as subviews to the DetailViewController's view.  This works for UIViewController derived views, but not for UITableViewController view types?.  Why would this be?

My problem is rooted in the fact that the manufactured DetailView is the UISplitViewController's delegate.  To get the correct popover behaviour, I'd like to keep it add buttons to its toolbar and then based on user selection open different details when master list selections are made.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a table view controller on the existing detail controller, it will get replaced and you have what you want.